# Can't get modal window to show

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble getting this bootstrap modal window to show up in Angular...any help would be appreciated.

When I click "log in", I know the `toggleModal()` function is being fired (I've tested it), but the modal window does not show.  The `visible=showModal` attribute in my `index.ejs` doesn't seem to work.

**index.ejs**

```
 <a href="" ng-click="toggleModal()">Log in</a>

        <modal title="Login form" visible="showModal">
            <form role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </modal>
```

**main controller**

```
    $scope.showModal = false;

    $scope.toggleModal = function(){
        $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
    };
```

**modal directive**

```
angular.module('TechStretcher').directive('modal', function () {
    return {
        template: '<div class="modal fade">' +
        '<div class="modal-dialog">' +
        '<div class="modal-content">' +
        '<div class="modal-header">' +
        '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' +
        '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>',
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        replace:true,
        scope:true,
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.title = attrs.title;

            scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(value){
                if(value == true)
                    $(element).modal('show');
                else
                    $(element).modal('hide');
            });

            $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
                });
            });

            $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap CSS and JS files in your website theme? If so, you're reinventing the wheel here.

Comment: @AchrafAlmouloudi yes I've included bootstrap CSS CDN at the top of my ejs (not included in the OP).  Can you explain why I'm reinventing the wheel if I'm making use of Bootstrap?

Comment: Alot of this can be done without making use of bootstrap. Also why not just use the login directive from a templateUrl. Your already requiring the current scope.

Comment: A modal is supposed to not be attached to an intermediate node but to the whole page in order to work. I guess this is why both angular-ui & angularModalService don't provide directive for this, it doesn't fit. If you don't want angular-ui-bootstrap you can take a look at angularModalService Which is compatible with bootstrap modal :https://github.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service

Comment: @Walfrat thanks for the information.  Are you able to tell me why the below jsfiddle works without issues, but when I try to implement it (via the above code) it does not work? http://jsfiddle.net/alexsuch/RLQhh/

Answer (score -1):

As a framework, Bootstrap already includes a simple mechanism to show/hide modals and takes care of the JavaScript involved in the process, so you don't have to write your own.

Here's how you can do the login form in a Bootstrap modal:

**Modal content**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="loginForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm dash-modal" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <input id="edit-type" type="hidden">
            <input id="edit-balance" type="hidden">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Login form</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">

                <form role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </form>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Modal opener**

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-target="#loginForm" data-toggle="modal">Log in</a>
```

I hope this helps out, please let me know if something isn't right.

Comment: IHowever if he wants to interact with it with angular he may need to perform some DOM manipulation from the controller, which is not angular way of doing this.

Comment: Any element can be manipulated by their ID including the opening button itself.

Comment: Yes but manipulating element from controller isn't the way of doing it in angular. This will work, but this is considered as a violation of separation of concerns in angular.

Comment: @AchrafAlmouloudi thanks for the code...as Walfrat mentioned, I wish to perform DOM manipulation, and therefore wanted to do that via a directive (since that is the "angular way").

Comment: I am sorry I'm not that experienced in AngularJS so I might have misunderstood the goal here.

Comment: @Flame1845 Could you please upvote my answer, it's not technically incorrect so I don't see why it was downvoted.

Comment: @AchrafAlmouloudi Unfortunately I don't have enough points to make my votes public, sorry